I want to expand all the nodes connected to a node in Memgraph using Memgraph Cypher
Basically, just like in networkx where you get all connected_components to a node, I want to replicate that in Memgeraph.
So basically if i have a node with a specific label ( lets say node named claims with CaseNumber:"SR02892923" ) and there are other node types connected to it. The graph which I have is directed. So i want to expand all the nodes which are connected to that node indefinite ( until they cant be expanded no more)
I looked far and wide and didn't found a viable solution. So I tried a workaround
Workaround
MATCH path=(c:claims {CaseNumber:"SR02892923"})-[r]->(m) WITH path MATCH path2=(n)-[e]->(m) WHERE n IN nodes(path) OR m IN nodes(path) WITH path2 MATCH path3=(n)-[e]->(m) WHERE n IN nodes(path2) OR m IN nodes(path2) WITH path3 MATCH path4=(n)-[e]->(m) WHERE n IN nodes(path3) OR m IN nodes(path3)  WITH project(path4) as subgraph CALL weakly_connected_components.get(subgraph) YIELD node,component_id RETURN node,component_id;
However this query is taking too long to complete ( more than 80 minutes )
I need something which explores all the nodes like networkx would and return me that graph. because then i want to filter the returned nodes
Does anyone know how to do this ?
I also tried to use dfs_tree but its not expanding all the nodes ( its just exploring in depth upto a point)
MATCH (source:claims {CaseNumber: "SR02892923"}) CALL nxalg.dfs_tree(source,15)  YIELD tree UNWIND tree AS node MATCH (node)-[r]-(neighbor) RETURN DISTINCT node, neighbor, r;

Could the standard DFS algorithm be what you're looking for?
If you run a query similar to this one:
MATCH path=(n {CaseNumber:"SR02892923"})-[*]->()
RETURN path;

it will return all paths that have the n node as a start node and since we didn't assign any values to the end node it will expand on possible nodes

Yes but basically this is just expanding all the nodes that are connected from my source( lets say a)  node to all nodes ( lets say b, c, d, e)  that have this relation ( (a)-->(b) , (a)-->(c), (a)-->(d), etc) Then b,c,d,e gets expanded to point to other nodes (lets say h,i,j,k)  Its not expanding the nodes which are pointing to the nodes say b, c , d, e ( like (b)<--(x) ) I want to expand those as well

Just checked, its not returning all the nodes possible

Could you try using the undirected DFS?
MATCH path=(n {CaseNumber:"SR02892923"})-[*]-()
RETURN path;

Yes I did that but then my memgraph lab crashes completely.
Instead I tried something like this
MATCH (n:claims {CaseNumber: "SR02422918"}) CALL path.subgraph_nodes(n,{       minLevel: 0,       maxLevel: 1,       labelFilter: ["-deviceid","-asset"] }) YIELD nodes // UNWIND nodes RETURN nodes; 
This should pretty much work right?

that's unfortunate that Memgraph crashed, what's the scale of the data you're working on and version of Memgraph?
If you found a workaround that's great, but I'd like to figure out why it crashed. Did you receive any logs?
